# How to convert a numpy complex array to a two element float array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray in numpy, which contains complex values. I would like to convert each to two float values. I tried it with `array` `real` and `imag`, but only the real parts are in the outputs

```
import numpy as np

inp_array = np.array([[1,2+3.j,3,4], [5,6,7+1.j,8], [9,10,11,12]], dtype=np.complex64)

out_array = np.array([np.real(inp_array), np.imag(inp_array)])
```

I would like to get this result:

```
[[[1,0],[2,3],[3,0],[4,0]], [...], [...]]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple and efficient way to do this is to make a `np.float32` *view* of the array, and then tweak the view to have shape `(m, n, 2)`, where `(m, n)` is the shape of `inp_array`.  By using a view, the output array actually uses the same memory as `inp_array`.

Here's your array `inp_array`.

```
In [158]: inp_array = np.array([[1,2+3.j,3,4], [5,6,7+1.j,8], [9,10,11,12]], dtype=np.complex64)

In [159]: inp_array
Out[159]: 
array([[ 1.+0.j,  2.+3.j,  3.+0.j,  4.+0.j],
       [ 5.+0.j,  6.+0.j,  7.+1.j,  8.+0.j],
       [ 9.+0.j, 10.+0.j, 11.+0.j, 12.+0.j]], dtype=complex64)
```

Make a view of the array with type `np.float32`.  If `(m, n)` is the shape of `inp_array`, then `v` will have shape `(m, 2*n)`.

```
In [160]: v = inp_array.view(np.float32)

In [161]: v
Out[161]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  6.,  0.,  7.,  1.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 9.,  0., 10.,  0., 11.,  0., 12.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now reshape to `(m, n, 2)`.  (`w` is what you called `out_array`.)

```
In [162]: w = v.reshape(inp_array.shape + (2,))

In [163]: w
Out[163]: 
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  0.],
        [ 4.,  0.]],

       [[ 5.,  0.],
        [ 6.,  0.],
        [ 7.,  1.],
        [ 8.,  0.]],

       [[ 9.,  0.],
        [10.,  0.],
        [11.,  0.],
        [12.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)

In [164]: inp_array[1,2]
Out[164]: (7+1j)

In [165]: w[1,2]
Out[165]: array([7., 1.], dtype=float32)
```

A couple notes:

- This method assumes that `inp_array` is "C contiguous".  That is, the data in the array is stored in contiguous block of memory in "C" order.  This might not be the case if `inp_array` was created, for example, as a slice of a bigger array.
- `inp_array`, `v` and `w` are all views of the same block of memory.  If you change one in-place, they all change:

  ```
  In [171]: w[0, 0, 0] = 99

  In [172]: inp_array
  Out[172]: 
  array([[99.+0.j,  2.+3.j,  3.+0.j,  4.+0.j],
         [ 5.+0.j,  6.+0.j,  7.+1.j,  8.+0.j],
         [ 9.+0.j, 10.+0.j, 11.+0.j, 12.+0.j]], dtype=complex64)
  ```

Answer (score 5):

The imaginary parts are there in your `output_array`, but the dimensions are not in the order you would like.

Try replacing the final line with:

```
out_array = np.stack([np.real(inp_array), np.imag(inp_array)], axis=-1)
```

or you could use `.transpose`:

```
out_array = np.array([np.real(inp_array), np.imag(inp_array)]).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

Both should give output:

```
> out_array
array([[[  1.,   0.],
        [  2.,   3.],
        [  3.,   0.],
        [  4.,   0.]],

       [[  5.,   0.],
        [  6.,   0.],
        [  7.,   1.],
        [  8.,   0.]],

       [[  9.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.],
        [ 11.,   0.],
        [ 12.,   0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data output exactly as you asked, you are going to have to type cast the data as an int

```
import numpy as np

inp_array = np.array([[1,2+3.j,3,4], [5,6,7+1.j,8], [9,10,11,12]], dtype=np.complex64)


out_array = []
for l in inp_array:
    for e in l:
        out_array.append(([int(np.real(e)), int(np.imag(e))]))
out_array = np.asarray(out_array)
print(out_array)
```